# Integration of good functions on the real line

Tags: real-analysis

We call a function good if it is differentiable everywhere any number of times, and it and its all derivatives vanish faster than any power of $1/|x|$. My question is that "should the integral of a good function over the real line be finite?".

Comment: $e^{x^{2}}$ and its derivatives do not vanish faster than $\frac 1 {|x|}$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: $e^x^2$ is not a good function, but $e^{-x}^2$ is.

Comment: Your function vanishes very fast. Your condition is that the function does not vanish faster than  something. Perhaps you didn't state the condition properly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've written it wrong. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Your function $f$ satisfies the condition $x^{2}f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$. Hence $x^{2}f(x) $ is bounded. Since the integral of $|f|$ over $|x| \leq 1 $ is finite by continuity and $\int_{|x|>1}\frac 1 {x^{2}}dx <\infty$ it follows that $f$ is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

"vanish faster than any power of $1/|x|$" is very fast. $1/x^2$ is enough.